# Multi class image classification using CNN

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, conv-neural-network, image-classification

I wanted to classify images which consist five classes. I wanted to use CNN. But when I try with several models, the training accuracy will not increase than 20%. Please some one help me to overcome this. Mostly model will trained within 3 epoches and when epoches increase there is no improvement in accuracy. Can anyone suggest me a solution or model or can specify what could be the problem?

Below is one of the model i have used

```
#defining training and test sets
x_train,x_val,y_train,y_val=train_test_split(x,y,test_size=0.2, random_state=42)
print('Training data and target sizes: \n{}, {}'.format(x_train.shape,y_train.shape))
print('Test data and target sizes: \n{}, {}'.format(x_val.shape,y_val.shape))
```

Training data and target sizes:
(2398, 224, 224, 3), (2398,)
Test data and target sizes:
(600, 224, 224, 3), (600,)

```
img_rows, img_cols, img_channel = 224, 224, 3
base_model = applications.inception_v3.InceptionV3(include_top=False, weights='imagenet',pooling='avg', input_shape=(img_rows, img_cols, img_channel))
print(base_model.summary())


#Adding custom Layers
add_model = Sequential()
add_model.add(Dense(1024, activation='relu',input_shape=base_model.output_shape[1:]))
add_model.add(Dropout(0.60))
add_model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
print(add_model.summary())

# creating the final model
model = Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=add_model(base_model.output))

# compile the model
opt = optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=1e-08, decay=0.0)

reduce_lr = ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_acc',
                              patience=5,
                              verbose=1,
                              factor=0.1,
                              cooldown=10,
                              min_lr=0.00001)
   
model.compile(
              loss='categorical_crossentropy', 
              metrics=['acc'],
              optimizer='adam'
             )
print(model.summary())

n_fold = 5
kf = model_selection.KFold(n_splits = n_fold, shuffle = True)
eval_fun = metrics.roc_auc_score 
model.fit(x_train,y_train,epochs=50,batch_size=50,validation_data=(x_val,y_val))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is it okay could you share the part of the code where you're fitting the model. It's not available in the post.

And since the output is not reproducible due to lack of data, I suggest you go through this link https://www.kaggle.com/kenconstable/alzheimer-s-multi-class-classification

It's really well explained and it has given the best practices of multi-class-classification based on transfer learning as well as from scratch. In case you don't find this helpful, It would be helpful to share the training script including the model.fit() code.

Okay, so here's the issue,
In your code, you may be creating a base model with inception V3, however, you are not really adding that base model to your `add_model` variable.

Your `add_model` variable is essentially a dense network and not a CNN. Also, another thing, although it's not a big deal is that you're creating your own optimiser `opt` and not using it in `model.compile`

Can you please try this code out and let me know if it works:

```
# function to build the model
def build_transfer_model(conv_base,dropout,dense_node,learn_rate,metric):
    """
    Build and compile a transfer learning model
    Input: a base model, dropout rate, the number of filters in the dense node, 
           the learning rate and performance metrics
    Output: A compiled CNN model
    """
    
    # clear previous run
    backend.clear_session()
    
    # build the model
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(conv_base)
    model.add(Dropout(dropout))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())

    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(dense_node,activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(1,activation='sigmoid'))


    # complile the model
    model.compile(
        optimizer = tensorflow.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=learn_rate),
        loss      = 'categorical_crossentropy', 
        metrics   = metric )
    
    model.summary()
    return model

img_rows, img_cols, img_channel = 224, 224, 3
base_model = applications.inception_v3.InceptionV3(include_top=False, weights='imagenet',pooling='avg', input_shape=(img_rows, img_cols, img_channel))

model = build_transfer_model(conv_base=base_model,dropout=0.6,dense_node =1024,learn_rate=0.001,metric=['acc'])

print(model.summary())
model.fit(x_train,y_train,epochs=50,batch_size=50,validation_data=(x_val,y_val))
```

If you pay attention in the function, the first thing we are adding to the instance of `Sequential()` is the base layer (InceptionV3 in your case). But you were adding a dense layer directly. Although it may get the weights from the output layer of the base inception V3, it will be a dense network, not a CNN. So please check this out.

I may have changed the variable names, although I have tried not to do the same. And, please change the order of the layers in the build_transfer_model function according to your requirement.

In case it doesn't work, let me know.
Thanks.

Comment: Now i included the fitting part and data information.

Comment: Have edited, please check. Thanks. Let me know if it doesn't work.

Comment: There is an error message
ValueError: Shapes (None, 1) and (None, 4) are incompatible

Comment: sorry, check now. The previous code had ```Dense(4, activation='softmax')```. Changed it to what you had in your code ```Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')```

Comment: OP says *I wanted to classify images which consist five classes*; so your setup with sigmoid is wrong.

Comment: True, even I was perplexed about it. It is supposed to be ```Dense(5, 'sigmoid')``` and the maximum of all 5 sigmoid values is to be taken the prediction class.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [model.fit()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#fit) to actually train the model after compiling. Right now, it has randomly initialized weights, and is therefore making random predictions. Since you have five classes, the accuracy is approximately 1/5 = 20%. Training your model may take time depending on model size and amount of data you have.

Comment: I have used mode.fit() also. How to avoid this random prediction?

Comment: Can you edit the question and show your whole code?  And show how much data you have also.